# PHP Variables to get a single answer

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php database for a fantasy hockey league and I want to add all of the players totals over a few year together, my example is here.  http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/cnghscorings.php?TeamID=1

So I want for instance to have all of the Mike Richards added together to give me a total of GP, G, A, PTS, etc. together so I can have one Mike Richards with all of his stats on one line. Is there any way of doing this easily? Or is this going to be way to complicated? Would someone be able to give me that code to get this started?

```
 //Get TeamID from URL
 $iTeamID = $_GET["TeamID"];
 $iPlayerID= $_GET["PlayerID"];
 $iSea=$_GET["Sea"];
 $oteaminfo = mysql_query("
 SELECT Players.FullName, Seasonteam.TeamID, SeasonStats.Sea, SeasonStats.GP,         SeasonStats.Goals, SeasonStats.Assists, SeasonStats.Points, SeasonStats.Pim,  SeasonStats.PlusMinus, SeasonStats.PP, SeasonStats.SH, SeasonStats.GW, SeasonStats.GT,   SeasonStats.S, Players.PlayerID
 FROM Seasonteam
 LEFT JOIN (Players
 LEFT JOIN SeasonStats ON Players.PlayerID = SeasonStats.PlayerID)
 ON Seasonteam.TeamID = SeasonStats.TeamID
 WHERE Seasonteam.TeamID=$iTeamID;

 ") or die(mysql_error());


  Print "<br><br><table border=1 cellpadding=2>";
  Print "<td><b><center>Player Name</b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>GP</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>G</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>A</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>PTS</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>PIM</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>+/-</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>PP</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>SH</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>GW</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>GT</center></b></td>";
  Print "<td><b><center>S</center></b></td>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oteaminfo))
  {
Print "<tr>";
Print '<td><a href="cnghlplayerinfo.php?PlayerID=' . $row['PlayerID'] . '"   style="text-decoration:none;">' . $row['FullName'] . '</a></td>';
Print "<td><center>".$row['GP']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Goals']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Assists']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Points']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Pim']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['PlusMinus']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['PP']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['SH']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['GW']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['GT']."</center></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['S']."</center></td> ";
Print "</tr>";
    }
    Print "</table>";
```

Comment: Umm... Add them together?? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition

Comment: Do you want to summarize by team? I didn't understand... Add them together?

Comment: @fmgonzalez I guess I am over thinking this, I am trying to get it so I only have one line for each player with his totals displaying to the right. If I add them won't I still be showing 4 or 5 copies of the player as I have multiple seasons showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to use a GROUP BY to get 1 row per player and then use the aggregate SUM function to get the totals of those statistics. Below, I show how to aggregate them for Goals, Assists, and Points. Take a look at the Group BY clause and the aggregate functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

```
SELECT Players.FullName, Seasonteam.TeamID, SeasonStats.Sea, SeasonStats.GP,
       SUM(SeasonStats.Goals) AS totalGoals, SUM(SeasonStats.Assists) AS totalAssists,
       SUM(SeasonStats.Points) AS totalPoints, SeasonStats.Pim,  SeasonStats.PlusMinus,
       SeasonStats.PP, SeasonStats.SH, SeasonStats.GW, SeasonStats.GT,   SeasonStats.S,
       Players.PlayerID
FROM Seasonteam
LEFT JOIN (Players
LEFT JOIN SeasonStats ON Players.PlayerID = SeasonStats.PlayerID)
ON Seasonteam.TeamID = SeasonStats.TeamID
WHERE Seasonteam.TeamID=$iTeamID
GROUP BY Players.PlayerID;
```

Also make sure you escape your input to prevent SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

I would recommend you use mysqli with prepared statements instead of the deprecated mysql functions.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php